# Option Strict and Anonymous Types dont go together?

Tags: vb.net, linq, anonymous-types

I have a Linq query that yields anonymous types. However, now I want to work with the parameters of this anonymous type and it does not seem to work.

```
For Each obj As Object in Query
Dim row As DataRow = obj.parameter
...
Next obj
```

Now the compiler throws an error on the expression obj.parameter: "Option Strict On disallows late binding". If I understand it right, the compiler doesnt know the parameters of the anonymous type. I tried Option Infer On (and removed As Object), based on Google results, but it didnt help. Which seems to make sense, because it always seems to be a widening conversion to me.

Is there anyway to fix this, or should I just create a custom type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that declares the anonymous type (i.e. the `Select` part of your LINQ query) must be in the same method as the the code that uses it and the `Query` variable's declaration must have an inferred type. You cannot access the properties of an anonymous type after it has been cast to an `Object` since there is no named type to which you can cast it.

So make sure that your LINQ query (or, at least, the part that `Select`s into a new anonymous type) is in the same method. E.g.

```
Dim Query = From prod In products
            Select prod.Name, prod.Price

For Each obj in Query
    Dim name = obj.Name
    ...
Next obj
```

Comment: Ok so the culprit is my IEnumerable declaration?
I was using Dim Query As IEnumerable(Of Object)

Comment: It looks like this solved it indeed.  Is there any "danger" by using option infer on that I should be aware of?

Comment: @Martao: There's no danger, in fact you pretty much need "Option Infer On" to work efficiently with Linq and anonymous types.